# How to select resistor value for LDR

Tags: voltage, transistors, resistors, relay, ldr

I want to try making an 230 VAC bulb that automatically turns on/off using

- a relay
- a transistor
- an LDR

I have collected the following components:

1. a 9 V battery
2. a 9 VDC relay
3. an LDR
4. a BC457 transistor

I want to connect a resistor to the LDR, but don't know what value of resistor to buy. I tested that relay, it needs a minimum of 6-7 VDC to turn it on.

Please explain how to calculate the resistor value needed.

Comment: Where is your schematic to know which resistor you refer to?

Comment: sangpo Sangpo - Welcome :-) The recent edit from user *der bender* mentioned some relevant points, and since you might not see their "edit reason", I will add them here: (a) When you edit your question to add the schematic already requested, please also add the link to the datasheet for the relay, to ensure that its contact rating is suitable for your 230 VAC bulb. (b) Did you *really* mean the BC457 transistor? Or did you mean the very common BC547? If you mean the latter, then please edit the question to fix that too. Thanks.